# C# Шаблоны и Списки

Tags: c#, generics

Есть класс `Colum<T>`, Есть класс `Row` со списком `List<Colum>`. И есть проблема, `List<Colum>` требует указать ещё тип `T` аки `List<Colum<int>>`, но мне не нужно это, мне нужно чтобы `Row` хранил в себе список `Colum` и не задумывался о том, какой тип шаблона у Colum. Что можете посоветовать? (знаю про dynamic, но пытаюсь обойтись без него)

Comment: может тогда `Row<T>`?

Comment: не получится, т.к тогда все Colum в Row будут типа T, а мне нужно, чтобы они разные были

Comment: в смысле разные? Приведите пример кода, что вам надо

Comment: `
Row row = new Row();
row.colums.add(new Colum<int>(5));
row.colums.add(new Colum<string>("5"));
row.colums.add(new Colum<bool>(true));`

Comment: Сделайте обычный класс `Column`, от него наследуйте обобщенные классы (`Column<T> : Column`), в `Row` храните список базового `List<Column>`

Comment: В ответ будете выносить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте обычный класс `Column`, от него наследуйте обобщенные классы (`Column<T> : Column`), в `Row` храните список базового `List<Column>`.

Просто как пример

```
public abstract class Column
{
    public abstract object ValueObject { get; }
}

public class Column<T> : Column
{
    private T typedValue;
    public Column(T value)
    {
        typedValue = value;
    }

    public override object ValueObject => typedValue;
    public T Value => typedValue;
}
```

Строка

```
public class Row
{
    private List<Column> _list = new List<Column>();
    public void Add(Column c) =>
        _list.Add(c);

    public void Print() =>
        _list.ForEach(v => Console.WriteLine(v.ValueObject));
}
```

Как использовать

```
var row = new Row();
row.Add(new Column<int>(5));
row.Add(new Column<string>("vasya"));   
row.Print();
```

Вывод

```
5
vasya
```